# QUdpSocket: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I try to use the following header file in QT:

```
#include <QUdpSocket>
```

but i get the error:

```
QUdpSocket: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You need to add Qt to your include path.

Comment: Also you may forget to add "network" module in your QT project

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you add

```
QT += network
```

in your `.pro` file?